# An error occurs during the operation to place Uri as bitmap in imageView

Tags: android, android-bitmap

```java
public class addBoard extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int GET_GALLERY_IMAGE = 200;
    Uri image;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addboard);

        final EditText EDTITLE = findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
        final EditText EDTEXT = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Button addPhoto = findViewById(R.id.photo);
        addPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, GET_GALLERY_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        try {
            Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), image);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Button backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Input_Title", EDTITLE.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Input_Text", EDTEXT.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Input_Image", image);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GET_GALLERY_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri selectImage = data.getData();
            image = selectImage;

        }
    }
}
```

If you run this code in another project, there is no error, but if you use it in this project, you *will* get an error. Why is that?

```
Error :Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
at com.example.toolbar.addBoard.onCreate**(addBoard.java:45)** // blue line
```

An error occurs during the operation to place Uri as bitmap in imageView.

Comment: "If you run this code in another project, there is no error" -- there should be. You are attempting to reference `image` in `onCreate()`, and you not assign a value to it until `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: wow.... thanks you are genius